# ToDoList : добавление в список всех элементов цикла, а не выбранного

Tags: javascript

Идея: при клике на добавленные элементы в зелёном списке они появляются перечёркнутыми в красном списке по одному за раз, а получается так, что один и тот же элемент списка появляется несколько раз. 
1. Почему так происходит, если событие должно происъодить на this?
2. Как это исправить??

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let ul = document.getElementById('ul');
let button = document.getElementById('button');
let ul_done = document.getElementById('ul_done');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let arr = [];
  arr.push(input.value);
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.className = 'close';
  ul.appendChild(li);
  li.innerHTML += arr;
  
  list();
});

function list(){
  let list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for(let i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
   list[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      this.style.display = 'none';
      ul_done.outerHTML += '<li>' + this.innerHTML + '</li>' + '<br>';
    })
  }
}
```

```css
#todolist {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
#todolist #tasks {
  min-width: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 25px 30px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
#todolist #tasks input {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
#todolist #tasks button {
  background-color: #093;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  border-color: #00b300;
  color: #ccc;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#todolist #tasks ul {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#todolist #tasks ul li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  list-style-type: circle;
}
#todolist #tasks .close {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#todolist #tasks .close:hover {
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
}
#todolist #done {
  min-width: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
  padding: 25px 30px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
#todolist #done ul {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
#todolist #done ul li {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div id="todolist">
  <div id="tasks">
    <input type="text" id="input" autocomplete="off">
    <button id="button">Add task</button>
    <ul id="ul">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="done">
    <p id="ul_done"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш пример не показывает ситуацию, которую Вы описали, из-за ошибки в данной строке: `ul_done.outerHTML += '<li>' + this.innerHTML + '</li>' + '<br>';` Замените outerHTML на innerHTML. А как решить проблему - смотрите мой ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый раз при выполнении данной строки - добавляется новый обработчик события:

```
list[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
```

То есть, ранее добавленные элементы получают дубликат обработчика при добавлении каждого нового элемента. Чтобы этого избежать, используйте именованную функцию.

И ещё нужно заменить `outerHTML` на `innerHTML`, иначе Ваш пример работает только для одной удаленной задачи:

```
function appendToDeleted() {
    this.style.display = 'none';
    ul_done.innerHTML += '<li>' + this.innerHTML + '</li>' + '<br>';
}
list[i].addEventListener('click', appendToDeleted);
```

Вот полный вариант:

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let ul = document.getElementById('ul');
let button = document.getElementById('button');
let ul_done = document.getElementById('ul_done');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let arr = [];
  arr.push(input.value);
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.className = 'close';
  ul.appendChild(li);
  li.innerHTML += arr;

  list();
});

function appendToDeleted() {
  this.style.display = 'none';
  ul_done.innerHTML += '<li>' + this.innerHTML + '</li>' + '<br>';
}

function list() {
  let list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].addEventListener('click', appendToDeleted);
  }
}
```

```css
#todolist {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#todolist #tasks {
  min-width: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 25px 30px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

#todolist #tasks input {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

#todolist #tasks button {
  background-color: #093;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  border-color: #00b300;
  color: #ccc;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#todolist #tasks ul {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#todolist #tasks ul li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  list-style-type: circle;
}

#todolist #tasks .close {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#todolist #tasks .close:hover {
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
}

#todolist #done {
  min-width: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
  padding: 25px 30px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

#todolist #done ul {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

#todolist #done ul li {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div id="todolist">
  <div id="tasks">
    <input type="text" id="input" autocomplete="off">
    <button id="button">Add task</button>
    <ul id="ul">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="done">
    <p id="ul_done"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```